# Why am I getting a "No value specified for parameter 2" error in Spring boot jdbc template

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

My sql query looks like:

```
select T.Col1
from (
select Past_Diagnoses_1 as Col1
from patienthistory
union
select Past_Diagnoses_2 as Col1
from patienthistory
union
select Past_Diagnoses_3 as Col1
from patienthistory
union
select Past_Diagnoses_4 as Col1
from patienthistory
) as T;
```

I keep getting an error on Spring which says No value specified for parameter 2
I am trying to union 4 columns together into 1 super long column.

This is a simplified code. I have 32 columns but for question I have shown 4

Java code :

```
  public UserTemp findHistoryByID(Integer Patient_Number) {
    String sql = "select T.Col1\n" +
            "from (\n" +
            "    select Past_Diagnoses_1 as Col1\n" +
            "    from patienthistory\n" +
            "    union\n" +
            "    select Past_Diagnoses_2 as Col1\n" +
            "    from patienthistory\n" +
            "    union\n" +
            "    select Past_Diagnoses_3 as Col1\n" +
            "    from patienthistory\n" +
            "    union\n" +
            "    select Past_Diagnoses_4 as Col1\n" +
            "    from patienthistory\n" +
            "    union\n" +
            "    select Past_Diagnoses_5 as Col1\n" +
            "    from patienthistory\n"
            "    where Patient_Number = ?\n" +
            "    ) as T";
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{Patient_Number}, (rs, rowNum) ->
            new UserTemp(
                    rs.getString("T.Col1")

            ));
}
```

Comment: Your sql looks fine, please share your java code that is throwing the error.

Comment: Check the edited post to see my java code